# Android Custom_listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have created two layouts. The second one is test_layout. This layout has only two EditTexts.

My question is: **why does this second layout show no output ?**

## MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

List<String> phones=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Iphone ","Samsang "}));
List<String> os=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"ios","Android"}));

class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    Context c;
        public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, R.layout.test_layout);
      c=context;   
            
        }
        
        @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(c.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             View cv=li.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, parent, false);
                TextView txt1=(TextView)cv.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                TextView txt2=(TextView)cv.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                txt1.setText(phones.get(position));
                txt2.setText(os.get(position));
            return cv;
            }
    }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(this);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    
}
}
```

Comment: cud u try and change the adapter to ArrayAdapter<String> and use a constructor that has three parameters ?? context, layout and one of the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

override getCount method in adapter:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return phones.size();
}
```

You could also change your constructor to:

```
 public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.test_layout,phones);
  c=context;   

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the getCount method

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return phones.size(); //or os.size();
}
```

This method return the count of rows to be added in your list view on the basis of your array list.
If you don't override this method, then no row will be inflated. If you override and you return zero, then zero rows will be drawn.

So it needs to return the size of the array list used.